# 0-RTT Handshake key storage location for quic

Tags: quic

I'm studying the quic protocol. On the quic's 0-RTT Handshake, I found out that if a client has ever connected, they authenticate to the server using the key obtained from the previous connection. So where is the key from the previous connection stored?

Comment: The standard does not demand a specific way to store the key. It is commonly stored in memory, similar to how TLS sessions spanning multiple TCP connections are handled.